# Cross Domain Form Submission Using Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, web-deployment

Hi I am new to Spring MVC. I am using the release 4.1.6 release. I have deployed my Webapplication named SpringMVCTest on Tomcat 7.0. I have deployed another webapplication named CrossDomainTest deployed on the same Tomcat 7.0 Server.

In the production environment SpringMVCTest is been deployed on the weblogic application server and CrossDomainTest is been deployed on the different application server websphere.

Now I have few jsp pages on the SpringMVCTest , now when I clicked submit button on these jsp pages they need to be submitted and some controller of the CrossDomainTest webapplication needs to be invoked. This is the original requirement but these should work fine on the production environment.

Now coming to my question, is the cross domain form submission is possible using Spring MVC ? If yes , then can you please tell me how to this, If no is there any other way? Is this a good design practice?

Answer (score 0):

I think cross domian submit form and if using Spring MVC or not is nothing.
If you need cross domian. You can use jsonp.  Click [here](http://json-p.org/).

Comment: I have already tried that option but I have found out that jsonp does not support the POST request.

Comment: I don't want to make any JSON calls I just want to simply submit the data of my form in the POST request and the data should be received by the controller of some other application.

Comment: if so. It needs to config proxy.But I don't know how to config weblogic or tomcat proxy, you can google.